# Dashboard Failes to load after sign in

Tags: codeigniter

After right login details,form redirects to same place 
This is my controller for the login
The login should be redirected to the dashboard after validation and database check

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();              
    $this->load->model('login_model');      
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { 
        redirect(base_url().'dashboard');
    }
}

public function index(){        
    $template['page_title'] = "Login";
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');         

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            redirect(base_url().'dashboard');
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('Templates/header', $template);
    $this->load->view('Login/login_form');
    $this->load->view('Templates/footer');
}
}
```

code for Dashboard
    class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

    $this->load->model('dashboard_model');

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect(base_url());

    }
}
```

Comment: Show code of dashboard function as well

Comment: first you have check your if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
          die('working'); // redirect(base_url().'dashboard');
        } condition is working or not;

Comment: The condition is actually, working On inputting wrong credentials it shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method

```
redirect('dashboard');
```

Comment: @drey_1, please change the your redirect(base_url().'dashboard'); .. use simple redirech('file_nam');

Answer (score 0):

Try site_url() as well. Make sure there are proper code(error free) of view in dashboard controller.

```
redirect(site_url()."/dashboard");
```